# フォーカスのデフォルトを設定するには

Tags: html, css

フォーカスのデフォルトを設定するにはどうすればいいですか？
first-childを試しましたがこれだと他をフォーカスしても最初のフォーカスが残っていまいます
これをフォーカスするたびにフォーカスが変わるようにしたいです

```css
ul {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

li {
  background-color: #111000;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

li:focus {
  background-color: #bb2a3f;
  font: 25px bold;
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;  
}

i {
color: gold;
}

li:first-child {
      background-color: #bb2a3f;
  font: 25px bold;
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>新着</li>
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>月間</li>
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>週間</li>
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>総合</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:focus-within` 擬似クラスを使うことで、フォーカスを持っていない場合の装飾を行うことが出来ます。

```css
ul {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

li {
  background-color: #111000;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

ul:not(:focus-within)>li:first-of-type,
li:focus {
  background-color: #bb2a3f;
  font: 25px bold;
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

i {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>新着</li>
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>月間</li>
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>週間</li>
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>総合</li>
</ul>
```

もしフォーカスを失う直前の要素に装飾を適用し続けたい場合は、 JavaScript を使う必要があります。

```js
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  ul.firstElementChild.classList.add("focused");
});

ul.addEventListener("focusin", ({target}) => {
  [...target.parentElement.children].map(el => el.classList.toggle("focused", el == target));
});
```

```css
ul {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

li {
  background-color: #111000;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.focused {
  background-color: #bb2a3f;
  font: 25px bold;
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

i {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>新着</li>
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>月間</li>
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>週間</li>
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>総合</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

HTML5にはautoforcus属性がありますがこれはinputタグのみ利用できます。
http://www.htmq.com/html5/input_autofocus.shtml
残念ながらul liタグでは利用できません。

CSSに書いてもあくまで最初の属性のCSSをそれに固定するという形になるため
それも意味はないでしょう。
HTMLとCSSのみだけでは多少煩雑なので、かんたんに実行できる方法としてJavascriptのfocusメソッドを利用をおすすめします。
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

```js
document.getElementById('hoge').children[0].focus()
```

```css
ul {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

li {
  background-color: #111000;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

li:focus {
  background-color: #bb2a3f;
  font: 25px bold;
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;  
}

i {
color: gold;
}
```

```html
<ul id="hoge">
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>新着</li>
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>月間</li>
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>週間</li>
  <li tabindex=-1><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>総合</li>
</ul>
```

```
document.getElementById('hoge').children[0]
```

この書き方はHTMLの中の「hoge」というIDの子供の最初のHTMLElementを取得するというものですが、
詳しくはJavascriptの使い方を学んで見てください。

Comment: focusメゾッドでやってみましたがうまくいきませんでした。最初のフォーカスが残りませんがデフォルトが設定できませんでした。

Comment: 参考までに、HTML5時点でも、<input>以外に<button> <keygen> <select> <textarea> で autofocus 属性が使えます。少し前に autofocus はあらゆる要素で使えるように仕様が変更されていて、Chromeは実装済みのようです。

Comment: @user37046 さん> 解決されたとのことですが、 `tabindex` 属性に -1 を持っているので、 `focus` メソッドを使用したこの方法は動作すると思います。